# htaccess redirect a subdomain of a wordpress network site to a page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I am currently running a subdomain WordPress Network at domain1.org.  One of the subdomain sites is domain mapped to domain2.org.  I am trying to add a subdomain to domain2.org that will appear as sample.domain2.org.  The problem is that the domain2 is pointed to domain1.  We don't use wildcards, we manually edit the DNS for each subdomain site (server admin rule).  Tried a redirect rule like `Redirect 301 http://friend.episode13.org/ http://episode13.org/friend/`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a vhost for `friend.episode13.org`, and in that vhost redirect to `http://episode13.org/friend/`:

```
Redirect 301 / http://episode13.org/friend/
```

Otherwise, you can try using mod_rewrite and in the vhost (or htaccess file in the document root) where the `friend.episode13.org` subdomain points to, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^friend\.episode13\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://episode13.org/friend/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually was able to figure this out but my solution is the exact same so I marked this one.